# belongsTo and/or hasMany usage in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, cakephp-2.0, phalcon

I am used to CakePHP and Phalcon where models are linked together using a foreign key and a `belongsTo` and/or `hasMany` etc by setting it once. So every time when I get the output of a query I can easily access linked table values.

In CakePHP I do this from the User model like:

```
public $hasMany = array('UserType');
```

In Phalcon I do this from the User model like:

```
public function initialize() {
    $this->hasMany('id', 'Models\UserType', 'usertype_id', array('alias' => 'UserType'));
}
```

Where in both cases when I get the results for a user I can easily access for example the UserType name using `$user->UserType->name`.

But as I am reading for Laravel this is done through a function like:

```
$user->getUserType->name;
```

I think this is extra work and it is not accessible in a blade, I am hoping that there is a simple solution just like in CakePHP and Phalcon

Comment: So what is your question? You want to access a property of a related model in Phalcon?

Comment: @Timothy he's learning Laravel coming from a background in cakephp and phalcon.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Jared and Timothy he wants to know how to make this relation in Laravel as he showed how its done in Cake and Phalcon.

Comment: Jedrzej, Everywhere. See for example https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships and http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/02/25/creating-a-hasmany-relation-in-laravel-5/. It would be nice if you could elaborate how it's done so I can use it like in cake as per my question